# Intermittent - Error: No space left on device

Tags: 15.04, fdisk, du

Having intermittent issues when starting and stopping searches. I get a

```
Error: No space left on device
```

intermittently.

Have done some searches and most fixes are related to inodes, which you can see is not my issue.

It looks like the disk is not offset correctly but I do not think that is the issue.

```
jake@server:~$ sudo service crashplan start
Error: No space left on device

jake@server:~$ sudo service couchdb start
Error: No space left on device

jake@server:~$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/server-root   92G   18G   70G  20% /
udev                  2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs                 396M  6.5M  389M   2% /run
tmpfs                 2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                 5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                 2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1             228M   40M  176M  19% /boot
/dev/sdb2             3.6T  1.9T  1.6T  56% /media/data
tmpfs                 396M     0  396M   0% /run/user/1000
jake@server:~$ df -i
Filesystem              Inodes  IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/server-root   6127616 348568   5779048    6% /
udev                    502768    506    502262    1% /dev
tmpfs                   506080    753    505327    1% /run
tmpfs                   506080      2    506078    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   506080      8    506072    1% /run/lock
tmpfs                   506080     12    506068    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1               124496    299    124197    1% /boot
/dev/sdb2            244178944 378101 243800843    1% /media/data
tmpfs                   506080      4    506076    1% /run/user/1000

jake@server:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 97.7 GiB, 104857600000 bytes, 204800000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00021678

Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048    499711    497664  243M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       501758 204797951 204296194 97.4G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       501760 204797951 204296192 97.4G 83 Linux

Disk /dev/mapper/VS1-root: 93.4 GiB, 100298391552 bytes, 195895296 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/mapper/VS1-swap_1: 4 GiB, 4299161600 bytes, 8396800 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/sdb: 3.7 TiB, 4000754696192 bytes, 7813974016 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: BE311C90-F065-11E4-BEC1-C48508D2F365

Device      Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1      34     262177     262144  128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb2  264192 7813973982 7813709791  3.7T Microsoft basic data

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crashplan ended up having a wiki for this exact issue
http://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/Latest/Troubleshooting/Real-Time_Backup_For_Network-Attached_Drives

The fix was adding

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=1048576
```

to /etc/sysctl.conf and restarting